# Display ELMAH error detail in my own page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I'm using C# and MVC 3.

I have a page where I can view a grid of errors that ELMAH has logged. I created this instead of using the elmah.axd page because I wanted the page to be styled the same as the rest of my administrative section.

That worked great, but I'd like to do the same thing for the error detail page. I like the way the ELMAH detail page looks, but it's its own page, and I'd like it wrapped in my styles and integrated with the rest of my admin section.

Is there a function within ELMAH that will render the HTML for an error like on elmah.axd/detail, so that I can throw it in one of my pages?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but this guy has written an interesting [article](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/03/integrating-elmah-to-aspnet-mvc-in.html). There's some source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/elmah-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a function, but you can always pull the data out of the storage container (xml file, SQL Server, etc) and display it however you like.

Comment: You made me curious, took a quick look through the source and there doesn't appear to be a function.  ErrorDetailPage.cs just goes to the persistent store then uses an HtmlTextWriter and they build that detail display on the fly per request.